# IndexIgnore not allowed here

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, web

I have downloaded `SimpleInvoices` open source application. It's `.htaccess` file has the following code

```
IndexIgnore *

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh|tpl)$"> 
    Order Allow,Deny 
    Deny from all 
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?$ index.php?module=$1&view=$2&id=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?module=$1&view=$2 [L]
```

I.e. starts with `IndexIgnore *` directive.

Unfortunately, this directive causes error on my Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 (running on Windows 8).

Why?